# Service без Activity. Где вписать IntentFilter?

Tags: android

Есть проект службы без `activity`. Службу будет запускать другое приложение.

В книге этого примера написано: Прописываем сервис в `manifest` и добавляем к нему `IntentFilter` c `action = "testservice"`.

Куда дописать фильтр, если в `manifest` нету раздела `activity`?

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.denis.testselfservice">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
</application>
```

Comment: На 100% не уверен, но я не так давно тоже пытался написать приложение без активити и столкнулся с проблемой что интент фильтры начиная с какой то версии андройда (5й что ли) не работали пока пользователь не увидит хоть раз какую либо активити этого же приложения. Это такая защита от скрытых вредоносных приложений. Хотя возможно это касалось только определенных фильтров, а не всех. В общем будьте готовы что активити таки придется хотя бы одну добавить.

Answer (score 2):

```
<service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
              //Вот сюда
           </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Собсна, а при чем здесь активити?)

Comment: Спасибо Андроид Андроид! С службами не работал и не знал что фильтры можно ставить не только в активити.

Comment: @Kamenev_D да незачто)

Comment: Я так понял в КитКат START_STICKY не работает? Или что-то не так делаю? Убиваю процесс в ADM, но он больше не стартует.

Comment: а по какому принципу он должен стартовать?

Comment: Если верить мануалу, то после завершения процесса с флагом START_STICKY, система должна его снова завести. Но не запускает.

Comment: Наверно в том случае, если он был приостановлен системой или в процессе запуска, произошел некий сбой. Точно, увы, сказать не могу